# GET method erroneously working with volatile PostgREST RPC function?

Tags: postgrest

According to the [PostgREST v7.0.0 docs](https://postgrest.org/en/v7.0.0/api.html#immutable-and-stable-functions), the `GET` method should only work on RPC functions which are declared with `STABLE` or `IMMUTABLE`.

However I find that `GET`s to a function declared `VOLATILE PARALLEL UNSAFE` seems to work just fine.

Anyone know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was corrected on the latest docs: https://postgrest.org/en/latest/api.html#immutable-and-stable-functions

Basically, a VOLATILE function can be called with GET. However, it cannot modify the database because it will be executed on a read-only transaction(INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE will fail).